# Sequelize adds 'id' column in queries whereas I already have a column defined as PK

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have following model definition:

```
const my_table = sequelize.define(
    "my_table",
    {
      tagId: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      column1: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: sequelize.table1,
          key: "id",
        },
        allowNull: false,
      },
      birthDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      column2: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: sequelize.table2,
          key: "id",
        },
      },
      column3: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: sequelize.table3,
          key: "id",
        },
      },
      column4: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: sequelize.table4,
          key: "id",
        },
      },
      column5: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
          model: sequelize.table5,
          key: "id",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      freezeTableName: true,
    }
  );
```

As you can see I have already defined tagId column as a Primary Key. But still on findOne and findAll i'm getting following error as Sequelize is adding 'id' column in the end by default.

```
{
        "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
        "parent": {
            "fatal": false,
            "errno": 1054,
            "sqlState": "42S22",
            "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
            "sql": "SELECT `tagId`, `column1`, `birthDate`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`, `column5`, `id` FROM `my_table` AS `my_table` WHERE `my_table`.`tagId` = '123';"
        },
        "original": {
            "fatal": false,
            "errno": 1054,
            "sqlState": "42S22",
            "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
            "sql": "SELECT `tagId`, `column1`, `birthDate`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`, `column5`, `id` FROM `my_table` AS `my_table` WHERE `my_table`.`tagId` = '123';"
        },
        "sql": "SELECT `tagId`, `column1`, `birthDate`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`, `column5`, `id` FROM `my_table` AS `my_table` WHERE `my_table`.`tagId` = '123';"
    }
```

Is there a way to avoid this thing? As I have already searched almost everywhere but everywhere it's written to define any other column as primaryKey: true and the issue should go away itself.
I'm new to nodejs and sequelize so don't know much about it. I shall be thankful for the solution.

Comment: I could not reproduce this error. Can you look at attributes in a registered model instance and check if there is `id` attribute?

Comment: what version of sequelize is this any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
my_table.removeAttribute('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model defined, in the model you must defined the primary key or multiple primary keys.

In my case, I use node js, I had the same problem and I solved it this way.

```
import { Column, Model, Table } from "sequelize-typescript";

@Table({ tableName: 'example_table' })
export class ExampleTable extends Model {
  @Column({ field: 'example_id', primaryKey: true })
  exampleId: number;
}
```